# How to show binary photo inside <img> tag

Tags: javascript, image, binary, base64

I am wondering if there is a way to use binary photo that i get from a server.

So for example I have this kind of url `mybackend.com/get_image?id=1` and as a response I get a photo.

This is the response that I console.log:

```
�PNG
IHDR
ռ��IDATx�� ���
U��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“E>�|�(�Q��G��“�HL}/�MwIEND�B`�
```

This value that i logged is binary i guess.
When I set `<img src="mybackend.com/get_image?id=1" />` it works because browser first makes GET network call and makes this binary show probably under the hood.

I found bunch of answers regarding this and it usually says that I need to convert this into base64 and than insert it into `src` attribute. But they don't bring me near to showing photo.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const base64Image = btoa(binaryImage);
const imageTag = `<img src="data:image/png,${base64Image}" />`
```

`btoa` has a caveat - the binary must have a specific string representation. The [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/btoa) explains how to work around this:

```
// convert a Unicode string to a string in which
// each 16-bit unit occupies only one byte
function toBinary(string) {
  const codeUnits = new Uint16Array(string.length);
  for (let i = 0; i < codeUnits.length; i++) {
    codeUnits[i] = string.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  return String.fromCharCode(...new Uint8Array(codeUnits.buffer));
}

// a string that contains characters occupying > 1 byte
const myString = "☸☹☺☻☼☾☿";

const converted = toBinary(myString);
const encoded = btoa(converted);
console.log(encoded);                 // OCY5JjomOyY8Jj4mPyY=
```

Though it may be easier to simply use a library which can do this out of the box, such as [js-base64](https://github.com/dankogai/js-base64)

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/js-base64@3.6.0/base64.min.js"></script>
```

```
Base64.fromUint8Array(binaryImage);
```

Comment: This is not working because of some strange character that it has it seems. This is the error: `Failed to execute 'btoa' on 'Window': The string to be encoded contains characters outside of the Latin1 range`

Comment: @MarioPetrovic hmm, interesting. MDN docs say "Note that btoa() expects to be passed binary data, and will throw an exception if the given string contains any characters whose UTF-16 representation occupies more than one byte. For more details, see the documentation for btoa()."  [Binary strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMString/Binary) . I admittedly have not used this function very much - I'm looking now

Comment: Ah nice, this is great. Thanks a lot